# IllegalArgumentException when adding cloud messaging api to GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, illegalargumentexception

I am setting up Google Cloud Messaging in an Android application. At the beginning, I initialise the `GoogleApiClient` in order to check whether the Play Services are available:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

Trying to run it produces `IllegalArgumentException: must call addApi() to add at least one API`, so I also need to add the GCM Api, but honestly I can't find it on the documentation. Something like:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(gcm.API)     <----- WHAT HERE?
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

Comment: AFAIK you **don't need** `GoogleApiClient` for GCM

Comment: It isn't strictly needed, but the documentation "strongly encourages" to use it in order to check whether the Play Services are available or not: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: you can also use `GooglePlayServicesUtil` to do this ... I see your point(API should be consistent) but ... use `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity)` then `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)` and then `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, activity,
                        request).show()`

Comment: indeed, that's what I'm going to do.. :/

Comment: Here is a sample that demonstrates using GCM without any other Google Play Services APIs
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is no way yet to use `GoogleApiClient` in conjunction with Google Cloud Messaging. Until then, we need to use the `GooglePlayServicesUtil` way.

Comment: thats a surprise to see wrong instructions in the GCM docs...</sarcasm>

Comment: GooglePlayServicesUtil is deprecated for this and says to use `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);` instead

Comment: Where did you see that @Dori ? I can't even find GoogleApiAvailability class

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/31016722/236743

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
GoogleApiClient apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(
                                  this /* FragmentActivity */
                                  , this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)                    
                .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
                .build();
```

Comment: GoogleApiClient is deprecated what should use instead?