# GooglePlayServicesUtil vs GoogleApiAvailability

Tags: android

I am trying to use Google Play Service in my Android app. As Google document says, we need to check if the Google API is available before using it. I have searched some way to check it. Here is what I got:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
        finish();
    }
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

But when I go to Google Api GooglePlayServicesUtil page,
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil

I find all functions are **deprecated**. For example, the method

*GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable* (deprecated)

And Google recommends to use:

*GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable*.

However, when I try to use GoogleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, I get the error message:

[image]

Comment: where do I find GoogleApiAvailability? I can't find it.

Comment: @mcmillab +1. I upgraded from 8.1.0 to 8.4.0 and `GooglePlayServicesUtil` is gone (which seem like a bad practice for a "minor" update) but I'm not seeing `GoogleApiAvailability` to use as a replacement.

Comment: When updating to Firebase checkout this:
http://www.etivy.com/googleapiavailability-missed-with-firebase-messaging-9-4-0/

Answer (score 213):

I have found the solution. In the `GoogleApiAvailability`, all methods are public method, while in `GooglePlayServicesUtil` all methods are static public function.

So to use GoogleApiAvailability, the right way is:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is : PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST

Comment: `private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;`

Comment: 9000, 1972, 42 what now ?

Comment: I would actually like to know the correct answer since "PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST" does not resolve in my case.

Comment: It's an arbitrary integer. You can make up the value.

Comment: Some prefer to set the value to something over 9000.

Comment: why GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance() sometimes returns null?

Comment: @OmarAbdan Does it really returns null sometimes?

Comment: getErrorDialog can return null

Comment: This entire Google Play Services library design is an entire mess. It's all flawed plus it's hard to follow, in addition with lack of documentation.

Comment: that is `requestCode` from `onActivityResult`, which will be called after coming back to this Activity.

Answer (score 65):

The class [GooglePlayServicesUtil](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil) shouldn't be used anymore!

Here is how the class [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) can be used instead - when for example GCM (or any other Google service) is needed:

```
public static final int REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES = 1972;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        startRegistrationService();
    }
}

private void startRegistrationService() {
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int code = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (code == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        onActivityResult(REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES, Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
    } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(code) &&
        api.showErrorDialogFragment(this, code, REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES)) {
        // wait for onActivityResult call (see below)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, api.getErrorString(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistrationService.class); 
                startService(i); // OK, init GCM
            }
            break;

        default:
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

`REQUEST_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES` is an integer constant with arbitrary name and value, which can be referred to in the `onActivityResult()` method.

Also, calling `this.onActivityResult()` in the above code is okay (you also call `super.onActivityResult()` in the other place).

Comment: Can you point to the source that claims that "The class GooglePlayServicesUtil shouldn't be used anymore!". The Google Play Services API is so confusing.

Comment: All methods in [GooglePlayServicesUtil](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil) marked as deprecated plus recommendation at the top of the javadoc to take the `GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_PACKAGE` constant from [GoogleApiAvailability](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability) class is Google's way to tell you: don't use the `GooglePlayServicesUtil` class anymore.

Comment: What if the device has an older version of Google Play services in which the `GoogleApiAvailability` class doesn't exist?  If we reference the class statically, even inside a conditional expression, won't it crash the app?

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede, `GoogleApiAvailability` is part of the client library. So it's code is compiled into the app => Don't worry about that.

Comment: You should not call onActivityResult(). It is meant to be called from outside, when another activity returns a result.

Comment: I do not have a link to Google doc stating that. That is obvious. You can call it just my opinion.

Comment: this has one error: `onActivityResult()` should not be called directly.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber it's a system method intended to be used with Intents and startActivityForResult(), mr Senior

Comment: Nothing stops you for writing a more adequate method instead of calling a wrong one either, but there you go.

Answer (score 11):

You will have to use **GoogleApiAvailability** instead:

```
GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(); 
int errorCode = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

`this` represents the `context`.

Answer (score 9):

> Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
>   it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK
>   from the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system
>   settings.

```
public static boolean checkPlayServices(Activity activity) {
    final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Logger.logE(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just putting a `.getInstance()` in between the two methods would do the game.

Comment: This is the most concise answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have added this as fun in BaseActivity class to be used in all places

```
    fun checkGooglePlayServices(okAction : ()-> Unit , errorAction: (msg:String, isResolved:Boolean)-> Unit){
    val apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
    val resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(
                this,
                resultCode,
                PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST
            ).show()
             // dialoe when click on ok should let user go to install/update play serices


            errorAction("dialog is shown" , true)

        } else {
          "checkGooglePlayServices  This device is not supported.".log(mTag)
            errorAction("This device is not supported",false)
        }
    }else{
        okAction()
    }
}

companion object {
    const val PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1425
}
```

use it like this

```
    (activity as? BaseActivity)?.checkGooglePlayServices({
        // ok so start map
        initializeMap()
    },
        { msg, isResolved ->
            if (!isResolved)
                context?.show(msg)

        }
    )
```

Or you can customize it as you want.