# I am trying to check for google play services without using the deprecated method any insight?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, deprecated

I have been building an app that requires location awareness and have just gotten location awareness to work using google play services.  The issue is, the only way I was able to find online to check if the services are available is deprecated.  I could really use some input on this is supposed to be done now.

Here is the deprecated version:

```
  private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31016761/1658267 - here's the solution

Answer (score 3):

```
/** Method to verify google play services on the device */
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note: private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;