# ConnectionResult.SUCCESS but still getting GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to create an app compatible to Android SDK 19 (Kitkat) that can generate a unique id. I am currently using `com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0` (because I see it is compatible to Kitkat) , and my code looks something like this

```
final int answer = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
if (answer != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Google Play Services is NOT available. Status Code is " + answer);
    return null;
}

// running in async
try {
    final AdvertisingIdClient.Info advertisingIdInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(context);
    return advertisingIdInfo.getId();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Unable to generate Advertising id info due to " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When running this against my emulator (Nexus 5 + Android 19 + Intel x86), I am getting `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS` in my if statement, but still getting a `GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException`.

I would like to know why, but can't seem to figure out.

Any ideas why?

> W/my.Class( 2376): Unable to generate Advertising id info due to null
>
> W/System.err( 2376): com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
>
> W/System.err( 2376):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.j(Unknown Source)
>
> W/System.err( 2376):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source)
>
> W/System.err( 2376):  at my.Class$1$1.doInBackground(Z.java:115)
>
> W/System.err( 2376):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   W/System.err( 2376):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>
> W/System.err( 2376):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>
> W/System.err( 2376):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>
> W/System.err( 2376):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>
> W/System.err( 2376):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Thanks,
Franz

Comment: is google play services is installed on your emulator?

Answer (score 0):

That might be because most of the methods in `GooglePlayServicesUtil` class is deprecated including `[isGooglePlayServicesAvailable][1]`. You can use below given code to check availability of google play services.

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

**Update :-** You need to upgrade play-service version from *7.0.0* to *8.4.0* in order to use above given code. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016722/googleplayservicesutil-vs-googleapiavailability) answer.