# Play Game Services - BaseGameUtils - android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: android, exception, dialog, google-play-services, android-windowmanager

I’ve had this problem for a while, and it’s increasing with increasing downloads.

It occurs in **showActivityResultError()** which brings up an error dialogue for connection issues to Google’s Play Game Services. I tested the default case (“No meaningful Activity response code, so generate default Google Play services dialog”) and that works Ok on my phone.

One thing – both **GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable** and **GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog** are showing to be depreciated, but I can’t find any updates – does everyone use BaseGameUtils for their Leaderboards/Achievements anyway?

Occurs on Android versions **4.2/4.4/5.0/5.1/6.0** so no real clues there.

Top devices: **Galaxy Note4 (tre3g) / Galaxy Grand Neo Plus (grandneove3g) / Galaxy Note3 (ha3g) / Galaxy J7(2016) (j7xelte) / Galaxy Tab4 7.0 (degaswifiue) / Galaxy Note4 (trlte) / Galaxy Grand Prime (grandprimeve3g) / Galaxy S6 Edge (zerolte)**

The sourcecode for BaseGameUtils can be viewed here:
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/basegameutils/BaseGameUtils.java

Cheers!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4019)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4062)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: 
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:574)
  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
  at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(BaseGameUtils.java:154)
  at <my game here>
```

Comment: Based from this ralated SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31016761/5995040), you can use `GoogleApiAvailability` for `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` and `getErrorDialog`. AFAIK, you should use [games package](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/package-summary) for achievements and leaderboard. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try making those changes and see how it goes. The crash is relatively rare WRT the number of daily sessions, but persistent.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer, and it's a very simple fix. It's actually to do with calling Dialog.show() while the Activity is in the process of finishing. It’s described well here:
http://dimitar.me/android-displaying-dialogs-from-background-threads/

The fix is simply putting
`if(!activity.isFinishing())`
before calling 
`Dialog.show();`

In my case, it’s before
`errorDialog.show();`
in method `showActivityResultError()`
in `BaseGameUtils.java`

Thant’s it. A couple of exceptions a week have disappeared.