# GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(...) not taking me to System Settings

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm working on some error handling cases in case of missing play services. I followed the code snippet that is commonly handed around for this case (cf. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016722/googleplayservicesutil-vs-googleapiavailability) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493465/check-if-correct-google-play-service-available-unfortunately-application-has-s)), to show an error dialog in case of 'user resolvable' errors.

--> This works great, the error dialog shows up as expected.

According to the [documentation by Google](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#getErrorDialog(android.app.Activity,%20int,%20int)):

> The returned dialog [...] will direct them to the Play Store if Google Play services is out of date or missing, or **to system settings if Google Play services is disabled** on the device. *(emph. mine)*

- Now, clicking the button in the error dialog correctly takes me to the play store to update Google Play Services *when they're outdated*.
- But when I go to the system settings and disable Play Services, the dialog **doesn't do anything** when clicking on the button.

Are there any specific circumstances that could prevent this dialog from working as advertised? Why am I not forwarded to the system settings?

Comment: you can check avaabiltiy if not show dialoge that lead user to google play 
if yes, so check version of goggle service if it is lower your version so ask user to update it