# How can I use GoogleApiClient location services with Google Api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, location

In a tutorial I'm watching the instructor uses GoogleApiClient for LocationServices like this.[image]

I know that GoogleApiClient is deprecated and we should use GoogleApi instead which incorporates all the Google Api's as per this article: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html

However, this article only talks about GoogleSignInClient and not location services at all.

My problems are as follows:

1. I cannot find anything when I ***even*** try using GoogleSignInClient. My only dependency is this: `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'`

By this I mean when I type: `private GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient`...nothing shows up.

2. I can't find any GoogleApi for location services(as expected, since even GoogleSignInClient isn't showing up)

What may be going wrong here?

UPDATE:

So his code looks something like this:

```
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;


fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
```

..but I need to translate it using GoogleApi instead of GoogleApiClient(since that's deprecated).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the video is referring to [FusedLocationProviderApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) deprecated API.

If you want to use Google Play Service API to listen to the user location you need to use the new [FusedLocationProviderClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient), you can find the official sample implementation [here](https://github.com/android/location-samples/blob/master/LocationUpdates/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdates/MainActivity.java)

Based on your use case, think about adding a fallback in case the device does not have Play services installed (like using the Android native API)

Sample code using the new entrypoint class (you don't need to use the `GoogleApi` class directly):

```
fun getLastLocationIfApiAvailable(context: Context): Task<Location>? {
    val client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    return GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance()
        .checkApiAvailability(client)
        .onSuccessTask { _ -> client.lastLocation }
        .addOnFailureListener { _ -> Log.d(TAG, "Location unavailable.")}
}
```

If you need to handle all the possible output of `GoogleApiAvailability` check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41690941/2910520)

Comment: Hi, thanks. However, in the video he is using FusedLocationProviderClient, not FusedLocationProviderApi. 'client' refers to the instance variable GoogleApiClient client

Comment: @CodingChap I've added a code sample. You don't need to use the `GoogleApi` class directly